# How to execute heroku cli cmd to reset postgresql addon as part of deployment's release phase

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli

I was wondering if it is possible to run heroku cli command for resetting postgresql addon db  as part of deployment Release phase. I have a node js graphql server application.  All I want is that once its deployed, then run a heroku cli command to reset the database before running my migration scripts. I have the following Procfile

```
web: npm start
release: heroku restart && heroku pg:reset DATABASE --confirm <HEROKU_APP_NAME> && npx prisma migrate deploy
```

However I get the following error:

> /bin/sh: 1: heroku: not found

Comment: Hey @nabeelfarid, have you found any solution to this yet?